# Calculate decimal value related to 4 byte hex array

Tags: math, hex

I am looking through a field of bytes with hex values. The first 4 bytes map to one real-Value, a number. Now I need to know what decimal value it stands for and how to get this information?

```
ByteA = '12'; that means '18' in dec;
ByteB = '01'; that means '1' in dec;
ByteC = '00'; that means '0' in dec;
ByteD = '00'; that means '0' in dec;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each byte gets multiplied by 256 ^ the position in the field, so it could be either:

Big-endian (most significant byte first)

```
18 * 256 ^ 3 = 301,989,888
 1 * 256 ^ 2 =      65,536
 0 * 256 ^ 1 =           0
 0 * 256 ^ 0 =           0
               -----------
               302,055,424
```

Little-endian:

```
 0 * 256 ^ 3 =           0
 0 * 256 ^ 2 =           0
 1 * 256 ^ 1 =         256
18 * 256 ^ 0 =          18
               -----------
                       274
```

Most programming languages have built-in hex to decimal capabilities.